Internal error System.ArgumentException: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via error
I inherited a C# application where It is calling a soap web service method. This soap web service used to hosted as http and It has been switched to https so I went to the web.config of the application and changes all the end points from http to https like this:
 <client>
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap"    contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="customBinding"    bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap12"  contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap12" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap1"   contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap1" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="customBinding"    bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap121" contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap121" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap2"   contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap2" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="customBinding"    bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap122" contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap122" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap3"   contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap3" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="customBinding"    bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap123" contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap123" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap4"   contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap4" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="customBinding"    bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap124" contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap124" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap5"   contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap5" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx"              binding="customBinding"    bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap125" contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap125" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap6"   contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap6" />
<endpoint address="https://WSM/service.asmx" binding="customBinding"    bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap126" contract="WSM.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap126" />
 </client>

and
  <applicationSettings>
    <EMICommunication.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="dataservice_Service" serializeAs="String">
        <value>https://WSM/service.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </EMICommunication.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>

When searching the internet, the common recommendation is to change the basicHttpBinding security mode to Transport but the issue I am having is that for this application there so many bindings defined and I am overwhelmed and not sure which to change. Any help would be appreciated.
Here are all the bindings for this application from the web.config
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap1" />
        <binding name="ServiceSoap2" />
        <binding name="ServiceSoap3" />
        <binding name="ServiceSoap4" />
        <binding name="ServiceSoap5" />
        <binding name="ServiceSoap6">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap7" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap12">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap121">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap122">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap123">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap124">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap125">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap126">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

Here is the more detail of the error:
Internal error
System.ArgumentException: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelFactory`1.ValidateScheme(Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.ValidateCreateChannelParameters(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.OnCreateChannelCore(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelFactoryBase`1.InternalCreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.ServiceChannelFactoryOverRequest.CreateInnerChannelBinder(EndpointAddress to, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.CreateServiceChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.CreateChannel(Type channelType, EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel()
   at EMICommunication.WSM.ServiceSoapClient.SendPagesFromPPD(String AppName, String CommaSeperatedPagerNumbers, String CallbackNumber, String Msg) in C:\Vault\EMICommunication\EMICommunication\Service References\WSM\Reference.cs:line 8693
   at EMICommunication.Paging`1.SendCommunication(IList`1 recipients, String message) in C:\Vault\EMICommunication\EMICommunication\CommunicationBase\Paging.cs:line 42
   at EMICommunication.Communication`2.LookupAndSendCommunication() in C:\Vault\EMICommunication\EMICommunication\CommunicationBase\Communication.cs:line 140

